# How to elinminate creating too many objects in this code php

Tags: php, variables, scope

This is function i created to call my database connection  and to insert and retrieve data from database

Is there any way to do it without creating variable for each function

```
//require('OrientDB/OrientDB.php');
require 'phpIncludes/PhpOrient/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOrient\PhpOrient;
//require 'phpIncludes/sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php';

//Used for insert and other non value returning operations just send the query to execute

function runInsertQuery($query) {

    $client = new PhpOrient();
    $client->hostname = 'localhost';
    $client->port = 2424;
    $client->username = 'root';
    $client->password = 'hello';
    $client->connect();
    $client->dbOpen('tabe');


    $result = $client->command($query);
   // var_dump($result);


    return $result;
}

function getId($table, $field, $value) {

    $client = new PhpOrient();
    $client->hostname = 'localhost';
    $client->port = 2424;
    $client->username = 'root';
    $client->password = 'hello';
    $client->connect();
    $client->dbOpen('tabe');

    $query = "select from $table where $field='$value'";
    $result = $client->command($query);

    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));

    //var_dump($json);

    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json->rid;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function runSelectQuery($query) {

    $client = new PhpOrient();
    $client->hostname = 'localhost';
    $client->port = 2424;
    $client->username = 'root';
    $client->password = 'hello';
    $client->connect();
    $client->dbOpen('tabe');


    $result = $client->query($query);



    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));



    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json[0]->oData;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
function runquery($query)
{
    $client = new PhpOrient();
    $client->hostname = 'localhost';
    $client->port = 2424;
    $client->username = 'root';
    $client->password = 'hello';
    $client->connect();
    $client->dbOpen('tabe');


    $result = $client->query($query);



    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));



    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

if i do it like  this

```
    $client = new PhpOrient();
    $client->hostname = 'localhost';
    $client->port = 2424;
    $client->username = 'root';
    $client->password = 'hello';
    $client->connect();
    $client->dbOpen('tabe');
    function insertQuery();
     {
       //body
     } 
   function selectQuery();
     {
       //body
     }
```

It throws me variable undefined error how to solve this 
I am new to php can you please help me with this

Comment: Use the key word `Global` http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: you should either inherit the `PhpOrient` to a new class and then use new class object or add those functions in `PhpPrient` class.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Agghhhh Dont use GLOBAL as a way of passing data that should go in a function parameter. Global is the first resort of those that dont understand

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thnx for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to wrap your `$client` initialization code in a function and then call that function in other functions, like this:

```
require 'phpIncludes/PhpOrient/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOrient\PhpOrient;

/**
 * 
 * @staticvar PhpOrient $client
 * @return PhpOrient
 */
function getClient()
{
    static $client;

    if (!($client instanceof PhpOrient)) {
        $client = new PhpOrient();
        $client->hostname = 'localhost';
        $client->port = 2424;
        $client->username = 'root';
        $client->password = 'hello';
        $client->connect();
        $client->dbOpen('tabe');
    }

    return $client;
}

function runInsertQuery($query)
{
    $result = getClient()->command($query);
    // var_dump($result);

    return $result;
}

function getId($table, $field, $value)
{
    $query = "select from $table where $field='$value'";
    $result = getClient()->command($query);

    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));

    //var_dump($json);

    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json->rid;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function runSelectQuery($query)
{
    $result = getClient()->query($query);
    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));

    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json[0]->oData;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function runquery($query)
{
    $result = getClient()->query($query);
    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));

    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great I was looking for something like this Thank you